# jsf form. lookup up primary key in popup form to be entered in parent form

Tags: javascript, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have a Java EE JSF/Primeface app with an entry form for adding/editing an entity.  Let's call it `Product` On that form is a field to specify the `Salesperson`, which would really be the Salesperson's `Employee Number`.  But most data entry users don't know the salespersons employee number off the top of their head.

I'm looking for a way to either click open a popup window where the user can put in a keyword or two, find the right B.Smith, J.Doe, etc..., click their name and have that appropriate employee number pop into the text box on the parent form.
Or somehow do this inline in the parent form where the user starts typing any keyword and ajax queries the employee database, appropriate salesperson is selected and the employee number replaces the keywords typed in the input text box.

A nicety is to have (in an non-editable state) next to the text inputbox with the employee number, the salesperson's full name corresponding to the employee number.

Or some variant of those.

I had this working in a JSP application using some hacked together javascript, but I'm having trouble porting the functionality to JSF/Primefaces and was wondering if this functionality is already available in either technology.  I've been searching for a solution for a while.

One of the biggest issues if I continue to use my old javascript is knowing the the parent forms textbox id to know where to pop the value in.  Using JSF form I'm getting things like `j_idt28:j_idt29`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to mess around with Javascript for that case, so you won't need to know the generated ids.

Since you use PrimeFaces, you may want to look into the [Autocomplete component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteBasic.jsf).

Besides that, you can always make use of the [f:ajax tag](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_ajax.html) to respond to user input and update fields according to it for example.